# Converting an ActiveRecord array to a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm using ActiveRecord to grab an account value but I just cant get the formatting correct...

```
Account.all.map { |m| [m.day, m.NetLiquidation] }.unshift(['Day', 'value']).join(",")
```

gives me

```
[["Day", "value"], ["04/09/14", "94465.80"],["04/10/14", "96403.90"]]
```

What I need is a string like so...

```
"Day,value\n" + "04/09/14, 97450.57\n" + "04/10/14, 96403.90\n"
```

I know I'm close, but any ruby wizards know a quick shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Account.all.map { |m| [m.day, m.NetLiquidation] }.unshift(['Day', 'value']).map(|x| x.join(",")}.flatten.join("\n")
```

Comment: Not quite there. I'll try to tweak it and get close.

Comment: Thanks TCSGrad. You got me closer. I found a better way, but is it considered sloppy?
     "\"" + Account.all.map { |m| [m.update_day, m.NetLiquidation] }.unshift(['Day', 'volue']).map{ |x| x.join(", ")}.join("\\n\" + \"").to_s + "\\n\""